# How can I check spelling in HTML attributes?

Tags: spell-checking, filetype-html

Vim spell check feature works great in most cases - it is even smart enough to distinguish code from literals and comments in most languages. However I have problems with HTML spell check:

```
  <div title="text with mistaek #1" data-text="text with mistaek #2">text with mistaek #3</div>
```

In example above only mistake inside `div` is highlighted (#3). It would be great to have all relevant attributes checked - at least `title` and `data-*`, ideally - configurable list of attributes.

Is it achievable via configuration or VimScript? Plugin will also do, but ideally it should be configurable for different `HTML`-like files (for example, ASP .NET MVC `cshtml` files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax items within which Vim will highlight spelling mistakes are defined using the `@Spell` and `@NoSpell` clusters. See `:help spell-syntax` (and the rest of the `:help spell` and `:help syntax` files) for full details.

The quick and dirty fix to get your desired result is to create a new file in your Vim config directory: `.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` with the contents:

```
syn region htmlString contained start=+"+ end=+"+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc,@Spell
syn region htmlString contained start=+'+ end=+'+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc,@Spell
```

These lines define the syntax highlighting for HTML attributes, and were copied from the html.vim file that is included within Vim's standard syntax files. I then added the `@Spell` cluster to the `contains` field in order to enable spell-checking within each syntax item.

In order to apply this only to "title" and "data-*" attributes requires fine-tuning the regular expression used for matching the items, and slightly more extensive editing of the way HTML highlighting works. Here's a solution that works for "title" attributes only:

```
syn region htmlStringSpell contained start=+title=["']+hs=s+6 end=+["']+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc,@Spell containedin=htmlTag,ScriptTag
hi def link htmlStringSpell String
```

N.B.

1. The regular expression now includes the name of the `title` attribute, and an offset so that this part of the syntax item is not included in the highlighting. (See `:help syn-pattern-offset`)
2. The syntax item now has its own name, and therefore needs to (i) be `containedin` all the syntax items that htmlStrings are contained in via their respective `contains` settings. (ii) have its own highlighting applied.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my answer to add the single-quote lines. (Working on the full fix)

Answer (score 3):

From `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim`:

```
syn region  htmlString   contained start=+"+ end=+"+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc
syn region  htmlString   contained start=+'+ end=+'+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc
```

To add spelling support, we need to add the `@Spell` keyword (see `:help spell-syntax`) like so:

```
syn region  htmlString   contained start=+"+ end=+"+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc,@Spell
syn region  htmlString   contained start=+'+ end=+'+ contains=htmlSpecialChar,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc,@Spell
```

You need to put this in `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` so it will override the default syntax rules.

Bonus tip:
The first line is for attributes in double-quoted strings (`attr="value"`), and the
second one if for single-quoted strings (`attr='value'`). You can also override
just *one* of these, so you can choose whether you have spell checking.