# Why does spell-check work poorly on my system?

Tags: linux, spell-checking

I'm using VIM7.4.488 on ubuntu 15.04 system. I use command `:setlocal spell spelllang=en_us` for spell checking.

It can capture some spelling error as well as words like `htb`, `Cref`, `iffalse`. However, it did not detect the error spelling `tehrmal` (thermal). Then I tried `ge agw obr tbg.`, and type the command again, the obvious incorrect words are undetected either.

Any way to fix this problem?

Comment: `end_us`? Is the end nigh? :D

Comment: Does this behaviour occur in an empty buffer? Do you still get this error if you enter :set ft=

Comment: Are you using `spelllang=end_us`? Because that's not valid. Also make sure spell checking is actually enabled with `:set spell?` and that you haven't accidentally added those words to the dictionary with `zg` in `~/.vim/spell/en-utf-8.add` (assuming you're using utf-8).

Comment: @muru Thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the typo in OP.

Comment: @JeffreyLai Thanks for your answer. It behaves normally in an empty buffer. And the problem is fixed using `:set ft=`. Please post your answer in the answer area so that I can accept it.

Comment: @user3813057 Some filetypes ignore spell checking in some regions; there is currently [no easy way to override this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2119/51).

Comment: Out of interest, what *is* the filetype that you were editing?

Comment: It's a tex file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you've got some conflict with file syntax, which can be confirmed by turning that off:

```
:syn off
```

For example, by default in vim files (Such as your .vimrc) spell checking is only performed in comments.